# How to get individual values from an array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to grab the individual elements within the `options` array and update their state to whatever the user inputs. My initial state looks like this `questions = [{ qtext : "", options: ["", ""] , answer: "" }]`. So far my method looks like this

```
handleAnswerText: function(e, i) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState({
        questions: this.state.questions.map((question, qIndex) => {
            if (qIndex === i) {
                return {
                    qtext: question.qtext,
                    options: question.options.map((option, oIndex) => {if (oIndex === i && qIndex === i) { return e.target.value} else {return option} }),
                    answer: question.answer
                };
            } else {
                return question;
            }
        })
    }); 
},
```

I know that `handleAnswerText` should know both the question index I want to update, and the option index within that question but I'm not really sure how to accomplish this.